# How to use indexWhere in dart when the list contains a map and I want to find the index of a certain key

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this list

```
[
  {game29HakakianSchopf: {assists: 0, points: 0, rebounds: 0, fouls: 3}},
  {game30HakakianSchopf: {assists: 0, points: 0, rebounds: 0, fouls: 3}}
]
```

How can I use indexWhere in dart to find the index that contains the key (for example, find the index that has the key 'game29HakakianSchopf')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
 var a = [
   {game29HakakianSchopf: {assists: 0, points: 0, rebounds: 0, fouls: 3}},
   {game30HakakianSchopf: {assists: 0, points: 0, rebounds: 0, fouls: 3}}
 ];

 final index = a.indexWhere((item){
   return item.keys.first.toString() == "game29HakakianSchopf";
 });
```